# The data is repeated on each tile

Tags: leaflet, geoserver

I have a few WMS layers generated by geoserver (data from postgis), in leaflet I'm creating layers using both **L.tileLayer.wms** and **L.tileLayer**. In both cases I have the same result - **there is the same data on each tile**. The data is repeated on each tile. The data is not on the correct coordinates. 
Hard to explain, you can look at enclosed [printscreen here](http://leaflet.solanska.eu/stack.png).

My code look like this:

```
var sondy = new L.tileLayer.wms('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/archeo/wms?bbox=-556182.167458477,-1031638.88186088,-556085.240458477,-1031526.68186088&width=442&height=512', { 
  version: '1.1.0',
  layers: 'archeo:sondy_5514>4326',
  format: 'image/svg+xml',
  crs: L.CRS.EPSG4326,
  maxZoom: 21,
  transparent: true,
  attribution: 'Map data &copy; Archeo'
  });

var lokalita = new L.tileLayer('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/archeo/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=archeo:lokalita%3E4326&styles=&bbox=17.001919195719633,50.3879944052749,17.00420450498308,50.38958109165828&width=512&height=355&srs=EPSG:4326&format=image%2Fsvg%2Bxml', { 
  layer: 'lokalita',
  opacity: 1,
  maxZoom: 21,
  transparent: true,
  attribution: 'Map data &copy; Archeo'
  });
```

Do you have an idea where is the problem? Is it in geoserver or leaflet code?

Thanks in advance, 
Markéta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ciao,
I am not an expert with leaflet but to me it looks like something's wrong in how you initialize your layers (for sure the WMS one, why you put the bbox in the source URL??):

Check this link:
http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer-wms

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. URL really have to be without bbox. There was problem with different coordinate system in layer definition on GeoServer and in Leaflet code.

Comment: Yes, problem was solved. I wasn't sure to which part of the code I should focused on. After you suggestion, I focused only to URL and I already got, how Leaflet generates tiles.